# Why is it designed to be {uri.var.variable} instead of using the plain {variable}?

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

I understand that the WSO ESB/EI users need to use "uri.var" prefix when they want to [allow a RESTful URI to contain variables that can be populated during mediation runtime using property values whose names have the "uri.var." prefix.](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB500/HTTP+Endpoint)

But why do we need "uri.var" isn't surrounding it with curly braces like  `a/{pathvar}/b` enough to determined that it is a variable? Is this a room for improvement in the future or am I just missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"uri.var" prefix is used to identify path parameters of endpoints that the ESB/EI needs to correspond with, these variables **should** allow the endpoint to be resolved to different values based on the values set into them.

"{pathvar}" are already used in API proxies to identify path parameters associated with API resources. The purpose of these variables is to allow mediation logic access to invocation time path parameters.

```
...
<resource methods="DELETE PUT GET" uri-template="/order/{orderId}" faultSequence="fault">
...
```

Since the intent is different in the two scenarios, having different conventions is justifiable.